# Magento 2 : How to implement Multi Select Category Filter?

Tags: collection, layered-navigation, magento-2.1

I Have a category filter in my side bar , i managed to apply category filter using layred Navigation (using cat=11 in URL using a get method form) , now i want to add another category to the filter how will i modify my existing collecting and add that additional category filter